# Redis Source Code Compile Failed on macOS Mojave

Tags: redis, macos-mojave

The Redis 5.0 source code has failed to compile on **macOS Mojave**.

The MAKE log can be found here: https://gist.github.com/eliu/c56bffc0f3dc5f6a826949af5b4483b2

I know Redis can be installed via `brew`, but I need to know the way to compile the source code on macOS. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Fix it when removing the following packages installed via Homebrew:

```
brew uninstall binutils openvpn bash gcc rocker
```